# Is there any way to pass the DEFAULT_SUBJECT as parameter to next triggered build?

Tags: jenkins

Is there any way to pass the DEFAULT_SUBJECT as parameter to next triggered build? like below:

Main_Sub1=${DEFAULT_SUBJECT}

I used this, it just prints the variable name instead of value. Can any one help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are talking about *Email-ext* plugin. The plugin can run scripts (search for *JSR223* on [the plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)). You can open a file and dump the contents of _${DEFAULT_SUBJECT}_ there, then pass the file to the next build.

Unfortunately, I do not know the scripting API and could not find documentation that readily explains it. Unless **someone else here** knows the API or where to find the appropriate documentation, I'd start with scripts in `[JENKINS_ROOT_DIR]/plugins/email-ext/WEB-INF/classes/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates` and use reflection in order to understand the API.